# How to delete an item from an object of ids

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

```js
const comments = {
  '1': { id: '1', text: 'please add code examples' },
  '2': { id: '2', text: 'examples would be great for this article' },
  '3': { id: '3', text: 'hi there' },
};

const removeItem = items => {
  delete items[1];
};

console.log(removeItem(comments));
```

I need to delete an item based on its unique identifier. This reads `comments` is already declared

Comment: Your code works fine. It logs `undefined` because you're logging the result of `removeItem` (which doesn't return anything), but if you log `comments` after `removeItem(comments)`, you'll see that the first item is no longer there. The *"`comments` is already declared"* error you describe is not present in the code you've shared.

Comment: Console.log out the comments array after you have called removeItem and it will look how you want it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete a specific id, and i am hoping that your object key will be the same as the id it has, you can change the remove item to accept the id parameter and modify the function a little bit so it will delete the object according to the key property.

```
var comments = {
    1: { id: '1', text: 'please add code examples' },
    2: { id: '2', text: 'examples would be great for this article' },
    3: { id: '3', text: 'hi there' },
  };

var removeItem = (items, id) => {
    delete items[id];
};

removeItem(comments, 1);

console.log(comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `delete` as you've done there is exactly what you want to do - but if you're confused as to why you're getting `undefined`, that's because you're not returning anything from the `removeItem` function. Try returning `items`:

```js
const comments = {
  '1': { id: '1', text: 'please add code examples' },
  '2': { id: '2', text: 'examples would be great for this article' },
  '3': { id: '3', text: 'hi there' },
};

const removeItem = items => {
  delete items[1];
  return items;
};

console.log(removeItem(comments));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but you need to console log out the correct thing after you have done your working.

```
const comments = {
  '1': { id: '1', text: 'please add code examples' },
  '2': { id: '2', text: 'examples would be great for this article' },
  '3': { id: '3', text: 'hi there' },
};

const removeItem = items => {
  delete items[1];
};

removeItem(comments);

console.log(comments);
```

Your comments array looks like this after running removeItem:

```
comments
    2: {id: "2", text: "examples would be great for this article"}
    3: {id: "3", text: "hi there"}
```

Comment: the way your remove item function is setup it would only ever delete the item in the `1` key.

Comment: this is what has been asked

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this:

A) When you want to remove an item from `comments` (variable or constant) only

```
var comments = {
    '1': { id: '1', text: 'Text A' },
    '2': { id: '2', text: 'Text B' },
    '3': { id: '3', text: 'Text C' },
  };
var removeComment = (n) => {
    // validation or check
    delete comments[n];
};
console.log(removeComment(1));
```

B) If you want it to take an object as an argument along with index (n):

```
var comments = {
    '1': { id: '1', text: 'Text A' },
    '2': { id: '2', text: 'Text B' },
    '3': { id: '3', text: 'Text C' },
  };
var removeItem = (items, n) => {
    delete items[n];
};
console.log(removeItem(comments, 1));
```

You are getting error already declared as you would have used `comments` for other constant or variable in your code somewhere in global namespace. Try using `var` (variable) instead of `const` and above code should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function that gets the comments and the wanted comment `ID` then it deletes that comment if found.

```js
const comments = {
    '1': {
      id: '1',
      text: 'please add code examples'
    },
    '2': {
      id: '2',
      text: 'examples would be great for this article'
    },
    '3': {
      id: '3',
      text: 'hi there'
    },
  },
  removeItem = (cmts, id) => {
    cmts[id] && (delete cmts[id]);
    return cmts;
  };
console.log(removeItem(comments, 3)); /** deletes the comment with ID=3 **/
console.log('*** second call ****')
console.log(removeItem(comments, 55)); /** nothing happens and the same data is returned **/
```